# Reception differences for Intel Centrino wireless card on battery/not on battery

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I have been noticing a disturbing difference in the connection quality of the Intel Centrino 6205 card on my Thinkpad T420s on battery vs not on battery when in areas of poorish wifi reception.  Specifically, while on battery, it seems to work reasonably well, whereas plugged in, it does much worse.  I have enabled the "Maximum Performance" option in the Power manager while plugged in, while on battery, it is set for "Medium Power Savings".  Regardless, in either case, the "Transmit Power" setting in the Device Manager dialogue is set to "5. Highest".  Does anybody know why this might be the case?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to "Maximum performance" while on battery?

Comment: Good thought, I hadn't tried that since it was working fine on battery.  I suppose it's possible that the additional power is somehow messing with it, although my first thought was that perhaps there was some issue with the power adapter/shielding.

Comment: Oh, I misread your question. I thought you said while on battery it was worse.

Comment: Nonetheless, it's an interesting idea - maybe the Windows power management settings are working counter-productively.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Intel's documentation on wireless adapter power management here: http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-032513.htm.

It looks like you can manually configure the power options for the card (at least in Windows XP).

[image: Centrino XP Power Management]